# Upload app para a Apple Store

Tags: ios, upload, xcode, react-native, app

Estou tentando subir um app na apple store usando o xCODE 8, porem recebo a mensagem de que não é mais possível fazer upload para a apple store usando o xCODE 8. Pelo que pesquisei é possível subir apps usando apenas a versão 9 ou superior. Alguém consegue confirmar isso?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1806/_index.html) a versão utilizada para publicar aplicativos é sempre a ultima versão.
Atualmente o xcode está na versão 9.0 porém já está disponível a versão 10.0 do Xcode. Que será disponibilizada com IOS 12.